# Gradle cannot find symbol class in Android Studio project

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Gradle has trouble resolving a dependency in an Android Studio project. I have a library that has a dependency to a java module called "common". I have the dependency speficied in the buld.gradle (see below), however, I still get "cannot find symbol MyClass" when building. How can I fix this?

The line in error is the import that references the package in "common".

Building works fine with maven, but not with gradle.

This is the build.gradle of my lib.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':common')
}
```

Comment: is `MainClass` with `protected`, `package local` or `private `modifier? Make it `public`